# Date picker with default date

Tags: android, datepicker

In my application i am using date picker for user to select date.ALso i am using database in my application,if user selects 1 particular item means i will fetch data related to that item and i will show it in another screen,in that it will have 1 start date,i have to load that date as default date in date picker..But it is loading the current date as default date but not the date fetched from database..Please help me..Thanks in advance.

My code :

```
 c = Calendar.getInstance();               
               SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
               System.out.println("After format");
               Date pickdefdate=null;
//             String pickdefdatepar=null;
               try {
                   System.out.println("Inside try="+date);
              pickdefdate=sdf.parse(date);              ----------->date which is fetched from database.
              System.out.println("dddddddd="+pickdefdate);

              c.setTime(pickdefdate);    --------------------->Setting this date as current date..
              System.out.println("After parse");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
               mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);             ----------as u said i am setting this value before dialog.
               mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
               mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);     
               showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);



 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
     {
            switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                System.out.println("in dia="+mDay);
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            }
            return null;
        }    

     private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        System.out.println("Inside dia");
                        mYear = year;
                        mMonth = monthOfYear;
                        mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    }
            };
```

Comment: Check What date is passed from your database, coz I executed your program and Its returning me correct date.

Answer (score 10):

use

```
    date_picker_dialog.updateDate(year, month - 1, date);
```

whenever you want to update an existing date into date picker.

If you want to set any date while create date picker then you can override oncreatedialog

```
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
    {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                date_picker_dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, get_date, year, month - 1, date);
                return date_picker_dialog;
        }
    }
```

hope it will help you. If any problem your are facing then you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

see `mYear_1`, `mMonth_1`, `mDay_1` are the fields in the date picker.

initialize these values before calling `showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID_1);` date picker dialog.

Usage==>

```
mYear_1     = 2011;
mMonth_1    = 07;
mDay_1      = 29;

showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID_1);
```

Don't use  `c = Calendar.getInstance();` like this.

Just intialize the values from the database to the these values

Comment: Thanks Ram kiran. But i am doing this only...I will explain what i did..The date coming from database is srting so i converting it into date and set that date as current date.Now i will get the day,month,year of current date(means date from database).Thats y i using calendar.getinstance() and also u can i see in code before calling show dialog() i have setted this value..See my edited post also..

Comment: this is simple way no. once check in my way and see. I too have same concept. I get success in it.

Comment: Ya ram kiran..I did in your way...Now what i am getting is when i am going to that screen one dialog box is appearing with fetched date with 2 optoins as "set"  and "cancel" .In that what i have to do.IF i click set means nothing is happening the today's date is showing as default date in date picker..

Comment: everything is right but i am so wonder why this is not getting any result.check this may use for you http://sree.cc/google/android/setting-custom-date-in-android-date-picker

Answer (score 0):

DatePickerDialog has a default constructor for this.

```
public DatePickerDialog(Context context,
            OnDateSetListener callBack,
            int year,
            int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {

    }
```