# Date picker with no default date selected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-datepicker

So I have a use case where I want to ask users to select a date from date picker, but when I call init function it takes the arguments for default(selected) year, month and day. Even when I pass -1 for all three parameters it shows a default selected date.
Is there any way in which I could use the date picker where by default no date is selected and the user is forced to select a date rather than carry on with the default date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date picker with default date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928354/date-picker-with-default-date)

Comment: Show what have you done so far

Comment: @gaurang it's not the same, I want no date to be selected by default

Comment: Yeah even I was wondering how to go around with this. @VikasTiwari I think the question is self explanatory and we don't actually need a code to understand.

Comment: If this is the case, then what is the use of your datepicker dialog?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible, a as soon as the data picker always "set" to some data (otherwise it couldn't response to users queries).

Maybe possible solution to you issue - is pre-set the data picker to some absolutely non-relevant old date (say, 1/1/1970), and check in the code the value. If you see this "garbage" - pop-up the message asking from user to set relevant date. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please explain what you did so far and what is not working? My suggestion was to implement your own code  - it will recognize "wrong" date (i.e.old date) set by user - and to bring kind of warning asking from user to set correct date. Is this what you tried so far? Thanks!